# How to print the supported language codes from SFSpeechRecognizer with supportedLocales

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nslocale, sfspeechrecognizer

I want to get the language codes supported by iOS's native speech recognizer, this is my code:

```
for(NSArray *subArray in [SFSpeechRecognizer supportedLocales]) {
        NSLog(@"LOCALES%@",subArray);
    }
```

In console, I expect some Locale such as "en-GB" , but get this instead:

```
LOCALES<__NSCFLocale: 0x1700d36a0>
```

My Objective C skills are a bit rusty now, how can I get those values in a readable format?

Comment: How about 
   `for (NSLocale *locate in [SFSpeechRecognizer supportedLocales]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [locate localizedStringForCountryCode:locate.countryCode]);
    }`

Comment: @nynohu Thanks for pointing the way, in the end, I used NSLog(@"LOCALESS: %@", [locate localeIdentifier]); to get the language codes. Add the solution as an answer and I'll give you the green tick.